# 2008 PT Cruiser 4cylinder non turbo

Tags: engine, chrysler, pt-cruiser, p0304

I have a check engine light and a generic 0304 #4 cylinder misfire. I have replaced the plugs, wires and now coil pack but the light reappears. I am a good mechanic but on construction equipment. What would be my next move? Fuel injector?

Comment: the injectors aren't known for failing, but it might be. try swapping the injectors around. i've seen more of these with compression issues. use a 194 bulb or a noid light to check the injector signal. another thought would be carbon buildup on the intake valve.

Answer (score 2):

Misfires are usually caused by one of 3 things:

- **poor/no spark:** you've addressed most of this with spark plugs and cables. Grab a timing light and make sure you are getting steady evenly spaced spark on each cylinder.
- **no/not enough fuel:** test your fuel injectors with a multimeter and measure your fuel pressure too.
- **low/no compression:** do a compression test on all 4 cylinders, make sure they are even and close to spec.